# Can you use React smooth scroll and React Router Links in the same website?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So I originally created a website with smooth scroll whenever I click my nav menu items, but now I want my buttons to link to additional pages to display more info.

My issue is for my styled components, I had to import link from react scroll to ensure they work, but now this conflicts with my nav button that I am trying to link with react router

```
 import { Link } from 'react-scroll';
 import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

I want my nav links to have react scroll

```
 export const NavLinks = styled(Link)``
```

But I want my button in the nav which is inside another div to use react-router

```
 export const NavBtnLink = styled(Link)``
```

Is that normal for websites to have smooth scroll and link to different pages? Or is smooth scroll meant only for one page static sites?

I don't get how I could have a signup button on a smooth scroll site if I can't link to a different page aka route

Code below

React Router not switching pages

React-scroll home nav link

```
           <NavLinks
              to='home'
              smooth={true}
              duration={500}
              spy={true}
              exact='true'
              offset={-80}
            >
              Home
            </NavLinks>
```

React-router nav btn

```
<NavBtnLink to='/signupa'>Sign In</NavBtnLink>
```

My App.js

```
  <Router>
  <Sidebar isOpen={isOpen} toggle={toggle} />
  <Navbar toggle={toggle} />
  <Home />
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/signupa' component={SignUpa} />
  </Switch>
  <Footer />
</Router>
```

My signup.js inside of my pages folder

```
    function SignUpa() {
      return (
        <>
          <h1>Signupa page</h1>
        </>
      );
    }

    export default SignUpa;
```

This is my home page that shows my entire site and the sections my react-scroll navigates to

```
    function Home() {
      return (
        <>
          <HeroSection />
          <InfoSection {...homeObjOne} />
          <InfoSection {...homeObjTwo} />
          <Services />
          <InfoSection {...homeObjThree} />
        </>
      );
    }
```

The HeroSection has the id="home" so it can scroll to that part, but I think that might be an issue now cause if I navigate to another page, idk how it will be able to take me back to the home page '/'

```
  <HeroContainer id='home'>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using alias name for import

```
import { Link as Link1 } from 'react-scroll';
import { Link as Link2 } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Then you can you accordingly the new alias name where you need!

Comment: so I added that alias, but when I try to click on my button it just updates the URL, but the actual page does nothing

Comment: I tried to add some, but not sure if that helps or if you need more details. Also, I already had a nav menu item called signup, so I just had to change my new page to signupa so it doesn't conflict with path names

Comment: Did you added the route to Switch? Which is not rendering anything?

Comment: `  <Switch>
    <Route path='/signupa' component={SignUpa} />
  </Switch>` I did this to test the component to see if something changes,but it didn't do anything

Comment: For to="home", can you try adding "/home" and where did you configured to display the Home on this route?

Comment: it's weird, but if I type a random url it shows just my navbar, then when I click on the signupa link it displays my entire content inside of my index.js page instead of my signup.js page.

Comment: I don't get how because i wrote above my function Signupa() which is just an H1 tag, then I wrote my index.js which is function Home(). Then in my NavBtnLink the to='/signupa' and my URL shows the link changing, but the actual component Signupa doesn't render

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-heisenberg-c2i3i?file=/src/components/Hero/index.js I added notes in the sandbox. Notice how the react-scroll adds the active class when you scroll and there is only one homepage section. But right when you click on the signup button it displays the index.js home page again, so it shows up twice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222372/discussion-between-veno-and-johnxr).